# Maps bug in interactive map

Tags: google-maps

I have been using google maps to show both static and interactive maps for years. But recently the interactive map is messed up and shows a location in the middle of the US.

Static map (works):
[http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=55.6494945,12.6222471&zoom=14&size=400x400&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:A%7C55.6494945,12.6222471&sensor=false](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=55.6494945,12.6222471&zoom=14&size=400x400&maptype=roadmap&markers=color%3ared%7Ccolor%3ared%7Clabel%3aA%7C55.6494945,12.6222471&sensor=false)

Interactive map (fails):
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:55.6494945,12.6222471

The interactive map puts a marker in the middle of the US even though that the streetview can find the correct location.

Any hints why the interactive map fails to display the correct location?

Comment: Looks like the [new Google Maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3092426) is not backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove word "loc:" from your url and seem working fine

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=55.6494945,12.6222471